# Change variable value on scroll - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, zooming

I have this variable: `coords.zoom`. I'm using the value of `coords.zoom` to set the width and height of a zoomed image, thus giving me a magnification effect. And it works great!

My only problem is that I don't know how to increment (or decrement) the value of this variable, when the user scrolls over my image. I need to create some function that will change the value of this variable on user scroll, but actually nothing is scrolling up or down. I would also like this variable to always be between 1 and 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Michelem Just a second...

Comment: @Michelem there is no special code. Actually, I only need to know how to make a function that will change the value of `coords.zoom` on scroll... in jQuery...

Comment: On scroll where? What do you scroll? The window? The element?

Comment: @Michelem OK, for the sake of the specifics, lets say you have an div. ANY DIV. When my cursor is on that div, and I scroll, I want the value of `coords.zoom` to change, and I AM NOT SCROLLING THE DIV (meaning I don't rely on the .scrollTop() function). Good enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a nice light solution to this problem. For anyone who needs this kind of mechanism, you've come to the right place. 
 
Let's say you have a div with the ID of `zoom`. To increment (or decrement) the value of my `coords.zoom` variable paste this code between your body tags:

```
<script>
   coords.zoom = 1.5 // set a start value to coords.zoom  
   $('.image').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
   if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0){ 

       coords.zoom = coords.zoom + 0.1;
       if (coords.zoom>3){coords.zoom = 3} // 3 is the max value of coords.zoom
       $("#zoom").text(coords.zoom);

   } else {

       coords.zoom = coords.zoom - 0.1;
       if (coords.zoom<1.2){coords.zoom = 1.2} // 1.2 is the min value of coords.zoom
       $("#zoom").text(coords.zoom);
    }
  });
</script>
```

There we go! Nice and efficient. Obviously, I've chose to increment the value by 0.1, but you can set it to any value in any range... Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

**It this code will execute when the document will be scrolled. And the code will execute in a proper manner with setTimeout.**

```
            var scrltimeout = null;
            jQuery(document)
            .scroll(function(){
            clearTimeout(scrltimeout);
              scrltimeout = setTimeout(
            function(){
            alert('document scrolled');
            }, 300)

            });
```

Comment: How does that change the value of my `coords.zoom` variable?